# Error while running haystack models in CPU

Tags: python, linux, hardware, huggingface-transformers, haystack

```
INFO:haystack.modeling.utils:Using devices: CPU - Number of GPUs: 0
Using devices: CPU - Number of GPUs: 0
'<' not supported between instances of 'torch.device' and 'int'
```

I am trying to run a QA model in my local machine which I took from huggingface.co . I have encountered this error. Has anyone seen this error ever? I am running this on CPU.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with that.